# Cell View constraints to Content View don't work on IPAD

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Using StoryBoard's Width Any and Height Any configuration I have been adding constraints to the CellView in relation to the ContentView

LeadingSpace from CellView to ContentView = 0
TrailingSpace from CellView to ContentView = 0

But when I preview this on the IPAD the CellView is not filling the ContentView.

I've set the ContentView background colour to Pink and the CellViews Background Colour to Red and here is the result:

[image]

Any ideas why the CellView is not filling the ContentView on the IPAD?

Comment: I think the constraint with cell view and content view are fine, problem is with constraint of UI label, As I can see with your UI, I believe u have used custom cell with custom label or inner view in it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it - but I'm don't think that is the problem.  The constraints of the descendent Views ie the UILabel within the CellView have not been set yet and hence they look a bit funny.  The CellView background has been set to red and you can see that it is not extending to the full width of the ContentView even though the the trailingSpace of CellView to LeadingView = 0.

Comment: Did you set the `cell.backgroundColor` to pink, or `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` to pink?

Comment: cell.contentView.backgroundColor

Comment: @LindaKeating if you can, in storyboard click on cell and select all so it show all the constraint that are applied to components inside cell. That way it will be easier to understand what is going wrong.